# Do you have to build a new compiler for a new operating system?

Tags: c, linux, compiler-construction, operating-system

I would like to build an OS some time in the future, and now thinking of some light sketches on how it would be. I have pretty much been coding in C compiled for the Windows environment (and some little Java). I would have to recompile any of my C programs should I want to run it under Linux. So the binaries, the product of compilation, must be different for each operating system. If I design a totally new OS from scratch, for both hobby and academic purpose, without using the Linux kernel or any known base code of an OS, what I understand as to happen is that I cannot compile my C programs with GCC since my OS will not be among its target systems. Here my question written on the title emerges. Thanks in advance for any hints.

Comment: I think by the time you've completed writing your own OS the answer will have presented itself :) But you might as well, yeah.

Comment: @cirrus after failing the 1st (and 2nd) attempt OP will know. But the head first approach requires to thing about it ahead - do it right the 1st time

Comment: Of course if you really want to go to the trouble of writing a new OS, why do something that's already been done. Rather than follow the layered kernel architecture & c-compiler model designed for a decades old paradigm, why not do something *truly* different like a functional or immutable OS (google Midori, immutable OS). With an immutable OS you could see great benefits in terms of security, size, performance and ease of concurrency. You'll almost certainly discover that C is a poor fit for your new platform and you'll want another language and possibly even a new type of language compiler.

Comment: @cirrus +1 for the Midori OS. From the same category of _truly_ different there are examples (3.2) and **mainly (3.3)** in my answer below

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It depends. You could easily choose to re-use an existing compiler, such as the immemorial example GCC, and thus you would reap the benefits of an existing compiler. But there are some big provisos that must be cleared up.

Regards of whether or not you choose to build a new compiler, the challenge will remain in porting a C library. You technically can use C without a standard library (which is what the Linux kernel, or any self-hosted example for that matter, has to do, for example) *but* this is a ridiculous proposition for programs intended to run under an operating system, as most systems impose memory restrictions, etc, meaning that you cannot just have carte blanche in terms of using memory. Thusly, a C library call such as `malloc` is required.

Since any programs under your kernel (99% of your OS in all likelihood) will need a set of functions to link against, porting a C library is your biggest task. The C library is a huge monolith, and writing your own would be rather silly, especially with [many implementations already available](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_standard_library#Implementations), the most well known being GCC's. So, the question you really should be asking is, do you want to write my own version of libc? (The answer is almost always no, and most alternative implementations are for niche use cases.) Plus, if you want to make your OS POSIX-compliant, then you'll have to implement *more* functions, adding to the hassle.

Whether you write your own compiler for your OS is a minor detail compared to which C library will be included with it. You can always use your own compiler with an already-written implementation of the C library.

My advice to your rather opinion-based question: **no**. Port an existing compiler such as GCC or clang, and then use that. Plus, that has several advantages:

1. Compatibility with existing tools and toolchains
2. A familiar program (no need for your users to learn how to use a new compiler)
3. They're open source - and in spite of that, you'd be insane to go at it alone. Heck, even Apple integrated two already existing compilers - GCC and clang - into their toolchains rather than do it themselves, and they're a billion-dollar company.

Take a look at [this page](http://wiki.osdev.org/Porting_GCC_to_your_OS). It demonstrates how to port GCC to your OS using [Newlib](http://www.sourceware.org/newlib/) as your C library.

Answer (score 3):

**(1) No, you usually don't have to** write your own compiler. Writing a good optimizing compiler can be actually big task which I would better avoid.

But in order to enable writing applications for your OS in some higher level language you will either need to provide

- some **(2.1) API emulation layer** (so that code written and compiled for other OS can be run on your OS)
- **or** you'll have to **(2.2) port some existing compiler** to your OS
- **or** at least make your OS a new available **(2.3) target platform** in an existing compiler
- or some other option I don't know about

The choices are multiple each with its own pros/cons.

Some examples (other then the obvious GCC already mentioned by @dietrich-epp, @sevenbits) to help you decide which way you want to follow:

**(3.1) Free Pascal** (see [http://www.freepascal.org](http://www.freepascal.org/)) compiler can be extended with another target platform

> > Free Pascal is a 32,64 and 16 bit professional Pascal compiler. It can target multiple processor architectures: Intel x86, AMD64/x86-64, PowerPC, PowerPC64, SPARC, and ARM. Supported operating systems include Linux, FreeBSD, Haiku, Mac OS X/iOS/Darwin, DOS, Win32, Win64, WinCE, OS/2, MorphOS, Nintendo GBA, Nintendo DS, and Nintendo Wii. Additionally, JVM, MIPS (big and little endian variants), i8086 and Motorola 68k architecture targets are available in the development versions
> >     ...
> >
> > <sub>Source: http://www.freepascal.org</sub>

**(3.2) Inferno Operating System** (see [http://www.vitanuova.com/inferno](http://www.vitanuova.com/inferno/)) has its own application language (see [Limbo](http://www.vitanuova.com/inferno/limbo.html)) with OS specific words, own compiler etc. Applications run in virtual machine (see [Dis](http://www.vitanuova.com/inferno/papers/dis.html))

> > Inferno® is a compact operating system designed for building distributed and networked systems on a wide variety of devices and platforms. With many advanced and unique features, Inferno puts an unrivalled set of tools into your hands...Inferno can run as a user application on top of an existing operating system or as a stand alone operating system...
> >
> > <sub>Source: http://www.vitanuova.com/inferno</sub>

**(3.3) Squeak** (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeak) is a self contained OS with graphics and everything. It uses Smalltalk-80 as the language. Compiler included, applications run in virtual machine (see [Cog VM](http://www.squeak.org/VirtualMachine)). The VM could be emitted as portable C code and then ported to a bare-bone hardware.

> > Squeak is a modern, open source, full-featured implementation of the powerful Smalltalk programming language and environment. Squeak is highly-portable, running on almost any platform you could name and you can really truly write once run anywhere. Squeak is the vehicle for a wide range of projects from multimedia applications and educational platforms to commercial web application development...
> >
> > <sub>Source: http://www.squeak.org</sub>

**(3.4) MenuetOS** (see [http://www.menuetos.net/](http://www.menuetos.net)) is 64bit OS written in assembly language. Flat Assembler (see [FASM](http://www.flatassembler.net/)) compiler which can emit native binaries was ported to the OS including OS API and is included in basic installation. Later on C library was also ported

> > MenuetOS is an Operating System in development for the PC written entirely in 32/64 bit assembly language...supports 32/64 bit x86 assembly programming for smaller, faster and less resource hungry applications...Menuet isn't based on other operating system nor has it roots within UNIX or the POSIX standards. The design goal, since the first release in year 2000, has been to remove the extra layers between different parts of an OS, which normally complicate programming and create bugs...
> >
> > <sub>Source: http://www.menuetos.net</sub>

**(3.5) Google's Android OS** (see [Wikipedia: Android (operating system)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))) ported Java Virtual Machine (see [Dalvik](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dalvik_(software)) later replaced by [Android Runtime](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_Runtime)) and provided OS APIs for the `Java` programming language, reusing existing compilers and IDEs just consuming the produced binaries

> > Android Runtime (ART) is an application runtime environment used by the Android mobile operating system. ART replaces Dalvik, which is the process virtual machine originally used by Android, and performs transformation of the application's bytecode into native instructions that are later executed by the device's runtime environment...
> >
> > <sub>Source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_Runtime</sub>

There are many more useful examples available. Whether you have to or don't have to basically depends on the programming paradigm your new OS will introduce. Why you want to build it and how will it differ from the existing ones.

Examples for **no** are: **(3.1), (3.4), (3.5)**

Examples for **yes** are: **(3.2), (3.3)**

Comment: Thank you for a great list of examples!

Answer (score 2):

No, you can just port an existing compiler.  You can even choose an existing executable format, such as ELF, and use your standard GCC + GNU Binutils toolchain.  You will need to port the standard library and C runtime, and you will need to write an ELF loader into your operating system.

I suspect the majority of the work will be in porting the C library.

A search turned up this page: [Porting GCC to your OS](http://wiki.osdev.org/Porting_GCC_to_your_OS)